# Switch to Tag Manager, will Enhanced Ecommerce still work?

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I've successfully implemented Google Enhanced Ecommerce on one of my websites, where I also have a Google Universal Analytics tracking code. Now we want to change to Google Tag Manager, thus replacing the UA tracking code with the Tag Manager Code (correct?)

Will this affect the Enhanced Ecommerce tracking in any way? Or can I just replace the tracking snippet and the ga('create')-parts with the Tag Manager-snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correctly set up dataLayer (which rather more complicated since you need info on product impressions etc). Documentation is here:

https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#enable

Then you create a news Analytics Tag (just a pageview or event, there is no need for a separate transaction tag) and select "Enhanced Ecommerce" with the "Use datalayer" option in the advanced settings.

GTM will pick up the values from there datalayer and do the rest for you.

So yes, you can get this to work, but it requires a lot of preparation for the correct datalayer implementation. Simply replacing the GA code with the GTM code will do very little except breaking your tracking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Eike. We're already measuring impressions, transactions, checkout steps etc, but we've done the implementation according to this guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#example

Comment: You need to create a variable (the "datalayer" that contains basically the same information your already use, but in the format specified in the linked documentation - GTM will then pick that up and do the ecommerce calls automatically.  Or you just run GTM and GA in parallel. But GTM will not use the GA code that's already in your site and will not pick up values from there.

Comment: Thank you for valuable information, Eike! So I can just add the GTM code in addition to what's already implemented (Universal Analytics and Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking)?

Comment: You can add GTM and deploy marketing tags etc along an existing GA implementation.  However you probably should not mix hardcoded GA code and Analytics tags from within GTM, since Analytics tags from within GTM create a randomly named tracker, so it will start a new session instead of reusing the existing session. Apart from that both tags work along with no problems.